# Validate the string parameter for its length and type

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have one Jenkins validation parameter which takes patch number as the input. I need to validate if parameter entered is a number and it should be of length = 8 chars. Could you please share the regular expression for this validation string parameter which validates both.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I would stick to groovy. Assuming your parameter is VERSION_NUMBER

```
if ( (params.VERSION_NUMBER).length() == 8 && params.VERSION_NUMBER ==~ /[0-9]+/) {
    result = 'valid'
} else {
    result = 'Invalid'
}
```

Alternatively you could just pile it all into a single regex and use `/[0-9]{8}/` and skip the length check.

Answer (score 0):

If your string parameter holdign patch version is stored in `patchVer` variable

```
stage('Patch version validation')
{

  sh '''

  echo "$patchVer" | egrep -q '^[0-9]+$'

  if [ $? -eq 0 -a ${#patchVer} -eq 8 ]; then 
    echo "$patchVer is a number and of 8 digits"; 
  else 
    echo "$patchVer is not a number"; 
    exit 1
  fi
  '''
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this input.